# Can use the intent-filter in android to start a method

Tags: java, android, nfc

me and a partner are working on a project and have designed an app that uses nfc, we want it so that when you're off the app you can tap an nfc card and read it as well, the problem is we don't specifically have an activity for reading or writing a card, its triggered using a button on main activity that starts a dialog fragment, starts a class and reads the card

is it possible, using the intent filter (or any other way without having to create an activity for it) trigger a method in the activity? at the moment we just have it to bring you to the main activity but we want to start a method in main activity when that happens.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc :)

Comment: nfc isnt the problem, we can catch NDEF_DISCOVERED in the manifest, but we want to start a specific method int the activity, and not just start it

Comment: for that you need to use intent-filter in onCreate()

Comment: how would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Intent filters start Activities.  Activities always start with onCreate.  If you want to call a single function in your activity, your code is mis-architected and that function should be in a common helper class, not in your activity.

Comment: is there anyway to identify an intent from the intent filter so we know when a specific intent is used, we can use that to call the function with an if statement?

Comment: Why are you zooming in on Intents and IntentFilters like this?  They're the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: because the main reason for this is to open the app using nfc when the user is not on it currently, the code for reading information in the nfc is written and we just want to run it. you're also not elaborating on the use of the helper class and just saying the idea we want is wrong.

Comment: @AbeGrogan Running code when the user isn't in the app doesn't require, or have anything to do with, an intent filter.  If you want to launch an activity to display a UI, launch it with a direct intent.  If you have functionality you want to run without being in an Activity, just put the code where it can be accessed by both the activity and the nfc receiver so both can call it.